# mini_magickをimportするとエラー: File to import not found or unreadable: mini_magick

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sass

現在、個人でアプリケーションを作成しております。
画像を投稿し、リサイズしてページに貼り付けたく、`mini_magick`を`bundle install`したのですが
`application.scss`に`@import`の記述をしたところ、

```
Sass::SyntaxError
File to import not found or unreadable: mini_magick.
```

のエラーが発生いたしました。色々と調べておりますが、原因が未だ分かりません。
アドバイスをいただけましたら幸いです。

**application.scss**

```
@import "bootstrap";
@import "font-awesome";
@import "mini_magick";
```

**エラー内容**

```
File to import not found or unreadable: mini_magick.
Load paths:
/home/ubuntu/workspace/otetsudai/app/assets/config
/home/ubuntu/workspace/otetsudai/app/assets/images
/home/ubuntu/workspace/otetsudai/app/assets/javascripts
/home/ubuntu/workspace/otetsudai/app/assets/stylesheets
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/bootstrap_form- 
2.7.0/app/assets/stylesheets
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/jquery-rails- 
4.3.3/vendor/assets/javascripts
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/swiper-rails- 
1.0.4/app/assets/javascripts
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/swiper-rails- 
1.0.4/app/assets/stylesheets
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/font-awesome-rails- 
4.7.0.4/app/assets/fonts
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/font-awesome-rails- 
4.7.0.4/app/assets/stylesheets
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/coffee-rails- 
4.2.2/lib/assets/javascripts
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/actioncable-5.2.0/lib/assets/compiled
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/activestorage- 
5.2.0/app/assets/javascripts
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/actionview-5.2.0/lib/assets/compiled
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/turbolinks-source- 
5.1.0/lib/assets/javascripts
/home/ubuntu/workspace/otetsudai/node_modules
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/popper_js-1.12.9/assets/javascripts
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/bootstrap-4.1.1/assets/stylesheets
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/bootstrap-4.1.1/assets/javascripts
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/bootstrap-4.1.1/assets/stylesheets
```

お時間がある時にアドバイスをいただけたら幸いです
よろしくおねがいいたします。

Comment: `mini_magick`はrubyの画像処理ライブラリなので、`@import "mini_magick"`のように`scss`にインポートできないと思います。`mini_magick`の使い方は[mini_magick](https://github.com/minimagick/minimagick)に記載があります。

Comment: マルチポスト　https://teratail.com/questions/145807

Answer (score 0):

https://teratail.com/questions/145807#reply-220991

> application.scssにmini_magickをimportする必要はないと思います。
> 下記のURLにmini_magickの使い方が書いてあるので読んでみてください。
> https://keruuweb.com/rails-minimagick%E3%81%AE%E4%BD%BF%E3%81%84%E6%96%B9/